# Run firefox in kiosk mode

Tags: firefox, xorg

I am trying to run Firefox without any window manager in full screen mode.

The command

```
xinit /absolute/path/to/firefox
```

starts firefox full screen.  However, whenever I try to open one of the menu options (File, Edit, etc.), the mouse pointer changes into a cross, and nothing happens (I can't open the menu with the keyboard shortcuts as well).
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the nodm package to solve this issue.

```
sudo apt-get install nodm
```